# Laravel | Change realPath value of file()

Tags: laravel, file, upload, store, laravel-5.6

Is it possible to change `realPath` attribute of Laravel file? I can actually move the file, but can't change the database record, as it's recorded as old realPath not the new path.

Here's what I get when I dump $request->file('xx');

```
UploadedFile {#476 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "Screen Shot 2018-05-07 at 6.08.05 PM.png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -size: 312932
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php"
  filename: "phpg4VH0Z"
  basename: "phpg4VH0Z"
  pathname: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpg4VH0Z"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpg4VH0Z"
  aTime: 2018-05-09 13:33:43
  mTime: 2018-05-09 13:33:42
  cTime: 2018-05-09 13:33:42
  inode: 2003589
  size: 312932
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 501
  group: 80
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

And here's my code:

```
public function store(UploadRequest $request)
{
    $path = public_path('/uploads');

    $project = new Project($request->all());
    $project->save();

    foreach ($request->file() as $file) {
        dd($file);
        $fileName = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file->storeAs($path, $fileName);
    }

    return $request->all();
}
```

I want to save the file inside public/uploads folder, with a custom name, and same path/name in database. As it's save as `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpGQhReP` for now.

Comment: You seem to fail to understand how PHP works, it first uploads the file to the temporary file and then its up to you to handle the rest, in reality you do not want to change the `realPath` you want to **move** / **copy** the file elsewhere. In order to do that please use whats already done in framework for you - read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#storing-uploaded-files).

Comment: @Kyslik I know how it works, I do move it already, but can't change the database record of realPath, that's why I want to change the realPath of database record.

Comment: Read the documentation - use `$path = $request->photo->storeAs('images');`

Comment: @Kyslik I already did that as you can see in the code above, but I want to change the database record itself.

Comment: `$path = $file->storeAs...` you failed to read the documentation, `dd($path)`. Update the record afterwards, but you will have more problems because you seem to want to save **multiple** files not just one. You better use https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary instead of your magic.

Comment: @Kyslik, could you please provide me with that documentation?

Comment: Its the link in my [**first comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50254921/laravel-change-realpath-value-of-file?noredirect=1#comment87527589_50254921) (last word is clickable).

Comment: @Kyslik, I already read this documentation, it's all about moving files to a new directory, but no database mention there.

Comment: So do you expect users to upload **one** file or **multiple** files?

Comment: Let's talk about one file manipulation for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, it assumes your `<input` with file is named `file`:

```
public function store(UploadRequest $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) { // depends on your FormRequest validation if `file` field is required or not
        $path = $request->file->storePublicly(public_path('/uploads'));
    }

    Project::create(array_merge($request->except('file'), ['file' => $path])); // do some array manipulation

    return $request->all();
}
```

And this for uploading multiple files:

```
public function store(UploadRequest $request)
{
    foreach ($request->file() as $key => $file) {
        if ($request->hasFile($key)) {
            $path = $request->$key->storePublicly('/uploads');
        }
        $keys[]  = $key;
        $paths[] = $path;
    }
    $data = $request->except($keys);
    $data = array_merge($data, array_combine($keys, $paths));

    Project::create($data);

    return back()->with('success', 'Project has been created successfully.');
}
```

Comment: But that doesn't move the file to `/uploads` folder.

Comment: Where does it move the file?

Comment: Yes, it woked, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the file like this

```
$file->move(public_path('uploads'), $file->originalName);
```

Comment: What about the database record, will it have the new path?

Comment: $project->images= public_path('uploads').'/'. $file->originalName;
$project->save()